# bootstrap affix.js not working when used as in independent plugin .

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

hey guys i am new to bootstrap 3.4 in general , but my Jquery is reasonably good . now i was trying to understand the code in affix.js and for that same reason i wanted to make an example of affix.js , so i picked up the entire code from [here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=enable-affix-via-javascript)(its a tut on how to use affix.js) :

now in that tutorial they are loading the entire bootstrap.js file , so all i had to do was replace bootstrap.js with on the code of [affix.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/affix.js) .

which i did , you can see the fiddle [here .](http://jsfiddle.net/qwraqu6m/) , but somehow something that should have obviuosly worked , is not working , i tried looking for errors in the console , but found none .

here is how i have initialized affix.js in my example :

```
$("#myNav").affix({
        offset: { 
            top: 195 
        }
    });
```

so why is my example(see the fiddle , see how the active states are not changing at all.) not working ??

Comment: As I see it, your Affix.js is working correct.  You need to include the bootstrap javascript  to control the navbar.  I include full bootstrap js into your fiddle and the menu is working correctly.  See http://jsfiddle.net/qwraqu6m/3/

Comment: @photo_tom , i only want to include affix.js , thats the whole point , i want to avoid loading the whole bootstrap.js file .

Answer (score 1):

You also need to include the scroll spy code.  Also, you should keep the header js that checks for jQuery is present.

You can see a working sample at http://jsbin.com/sejaka/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: "You also need to include the scroll spy code" , where do i find the  "scroll spy code" ?? +1 for trying :)

Comment: It is in bootstrap.js.